# Delete tabulation character from text retrieved with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, string, jsoup

I'm parsing a HTML file using Jsoup. When getting the text of a h1 it retrieves also tabulations and newlines.

'Name' is what I'm trying to retreive from here:

```
<h1>\n\t\t\tNAME\n\t\t</h1>
```

I'm trying to get rid of these characters this way:

```
String name = document.select( "div header > h1" ).first().ownText().replaceAll( "[^a-zA-Z]+", "" ).trim().toUpperCase();
```

But this is the result:

```
NTTTTNAMETNTTT
```

How can I get the text without all the tabulations and newlines characters?

Comment: That should work. is document of type Document? Maybe provide more code or the actual html.

Comment: It appears that your document actually has the characters '\' followed by 'n', '\' followed by 't' and so on, rather than a newline and a tab. Can you verify this?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I'm printing the original string and it prints '\t' and '\n'. How can I delete these character then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the html really contains the strings `"\t"` and `"\n"` literally. In that case you probably should clean the source prior to parsing. Something like this should do:

```
String html = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").execute().body();
html = html.replaceAll("\\\\[nt]", "");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```